# Django Allauth modify emails url from 127.0.0.0 to server domain name

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-allauth

Django Allauth modify emails url from 127.0.0.0 to server domain name

There is Nginx running on a Ubuntu server. The Django contrib Sites has domain.

The emails sent by Django allauth are:

```
Account activate
    http://127.0.0.1:8080/accounts/confirm-email/Ng:1dJZDR:VG7ds1v0HnQKHKzdgXLHRqfL1w4/

Password reset
   http://127.0.0.1:8080/accounts/password/reset/key/3-4ms-081fe4fdd341442cd244/
```

Of course, I would like use domain example.com instead of 127.0.0.1:8080

Could find any thing related to Domain at
    http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html

Comment: This is most likely because you use the development web server in production instead of a proper WSGI setup,

Comment: The problem was Nginx with adding heading resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Nginx, adding following header resolved it.

Add proxy_set_header Host $http_host; into your nginx configuration before options proxy_pass.